# "Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-reactivity

I need to display the `item.title` outside the `<v-carousel>` but I get this error message:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

I checked the results from the Stackoverflow search but I really struggle to understand it. I would be grateful if somebody could explain it to me by this example.
Here is my code:

```
<v-carousel>
<v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" v-bind:src="item.src" :key="i">
</v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>

<h1>TITLE: {{ item.title }}</h1>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            src: '/static/a.jpg',
            title: 'A',
            text: 'texta'
          },
          {
            src: '/static/b.jpg',
            title: 'B',
            text: 'textb'
          }
          {
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is what I need to archive:

As soon as an image changes to the next one - the a text **outside** of the  scope should change too. I tried to check the value of the item array outside the scope but it didn't work:
`<h1 v-if="(item,i) === 1">Lion</h1> <h1 v-if="(item,i) === 2">Ape</h1>`
How to access the value of the current carousel item outside of the scope?

Comment: in your example `item` is within `v-carousel-item` scope, so you can't use it outside. Now it all depends what you really want to achieve. (which title needs to be inside `h1`, or should every `v-carousel-item` have it's own title)

Comment: @Traxo Thanks for the explanation. This is what I need to archive: As soon as an image changes to the next one - the title text outside of the `<v-carousel>` scope should change too. I tried to check the value of the item array outside the scope but it didn't work: `<h1 v-if="(item,i) === 1">Lion</h1>
<h1 v-if="(item,i) === 2">Ape</h1>`

Comment: Please if you find time, just update your question so it's more clear what you are trying to achieve, so it doesn't just sit here in the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `v-model` on `v-carousel` component:

```
<v-carousel v-model="carousel">
    <v-carousel-item 
        v-for="(item,i) in items"
        v-bind:src="item.src"          
        :key="i"
    ></v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
//then set title like this:
<h1>TITLE: {{ items[carousel].title }}</h1>
```

And add `carousel` variable to `data`

```
data () {
  return {
    carousel: 0, //like this
    items: [
       ...
```